# How to allow access to ports 9735 and 10009 on an AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: lightning-network-daemon

I am trying to allow access to ports 9735 and 10009 on an AWS EC2 instance as per https://github.com/alexbosworth/run-lnd

My instance currently has 2 security groups and I am not sure how to proceed:
Do I create a new security group or use one of the existing groups?
Do I add Inbound and Outbound rules?
What goes in the Type dropdown, Protocol dropdown, Port range, source and box with the magnifying glass?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to use the same security groups you have at the moment. Just create two inbound TCP rules, one for port 9735 and the other for 10009, CIDR block should be 0.0.0.0/0 as anyone should be able to communicate with your node, unless you explicitly don't want to. Good luck!